# SlideUp Slide Down from multiple radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to slide up or slide down a div depending on radio button selection.
I added the following jQuery

```
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions2').hide();


$('#attrib-1-230, #attrib-1-231, #attrib-1-232').click(function () {
    $('.wrapperAttribsOptions3, .layoutMessage, .item_number1').slideDown(800);
```

This does work for the three i selected but i need to enhance it.

My question is, How can i make it slide up if NO #attrib-1-xxx radio button is selected, and if i need to add more to make it slide down do i have to add each one individually, ie #attrib-1-233, #attrib-1-234, OR is it possible to make it slide down if ANY #attrib-1-xxx is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to add a class to your clickable elements, and use that as your selector to generate your wrapped set:

```
$('.radio-button-to-expose-slider').click(function () {
    $('.wrapperAttribsOptions3, .layoutMessage, .item_number1').slideDown(800);
});
```

The code you posted above

```
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions2').hide();
```

should start that div hidden. However, if you know you always want it hidden, why not give the class `wrapperAttribsOptions2` a `display: none` in CSS, so it starts out hidden, then only expose it when you see the appropriate event?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Hadn't even considered that option. They already had <span class="SizeAttribute1">, <span class="SizeAttribute2"> so i just made them <span class=" sizeRadio SizeAttribute1"> and used sizeRadio as the class to hide/unhide the div

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop and use a selector with a variable like this:

```
$("#attrib-1-" + inputID);
```

Where inputID varies in the range you want your selectors to be in.